# Android: Radiobutton non checked

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I want to do an Android App Quiz. I did a radiogroup with 4 radiobuttons that represent the 4 answers. 
I want that when these radiobuttons aren't clicked the app shows an error, but my doesn't do it.
This my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        RadioGroup champ=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answer1);


        champ.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("null")
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch(checkedId) {

                    case R.id.answer1A:
                        ans1 =0;
                        break;
                    case R.id.answer1B:
                        ans1 =1;
                        break;
                    case R.id.answer1C:
                        ans1 =2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.answer1D:
                        ans1 =3;
                        break;
                    case R.id.answer1E:
                        ans1 =4;
                        break;
                    default:
                        ans1=(Integer) null;
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    }
                }
            });
```

Why?Can you help me, please?

Comment: you are checking it on listener..just check it outside listener..if any radiobutton is clicked or not..if not then show the toast..

Answer (score 0):

First assign:

```
ans1=-1; //in onCreate or at the time of declaration
```

You might be having a button or something clicking on which you would be accessing which answer was checked, there you can check :

```
if(ans1==-1)
{
   //show error message
}
else
{
  //Success
}
```

Comment: Modifico il mio codice in questo modo: 
if (champ.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
  {
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  else {
   champ.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This check is not executing  because this is a checkedchangelistener  which will trigger when you click on some radiobutton (when status is changed).

All you have to do is Check the status of the each and every radiobutton outside this listener.

Comment: very unclear answer. please elaborte or give an example how it can work. -1 for incomplete and misleading answer.